# Angular 12 ActivatedRoute get always undifined

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

A make a code according to a tutorial but me doesnt work because the activatedRoute params always empty even though i change the url.Maybe its changed in Angular 12 because the the tutorial was in version 11.Im comming from react and i am beginner with Angular and by choice i would make this with states not params.
And i had an other problem as well: 'details/:id' doesnt show up the DetailsComponent when i
toggle an url for example like this localhost:4200/details/15
Thanks for the help

this is my routing modul:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DetailsComponent } from './components/details/details.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'search/:sparam',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'details/:id',
    component: DetailsComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

And this my component where the magic would happen.But the params['sparam'] doesnt change when i change the url

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { APIResponse, Game } from '../../model/model';
import { HttpService } from 'src/app/services/http.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public sort: string;
  public games: Array<Game>;
  private routeSub: Subscription;
  private gameSub: Subscription;
  public str: string;
  constructor(
    private httpService: HttpService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      if (params['sparam']) {
        this.searchGames('-added', params['sparam']);
        console.log(params['sparam']);
      } else {
        this.searchGames('-added');
        console.log(params['sparam']);
      }
    });
  }

  searchGames(sort: string, search?: string): void {
    this.gameSub = this.httpService
      .getGamesList(sort, search)
      .subscribe((gameList: APIResponse<Game>) => {
        this.games = gameList.results;
        console.log(this.games);
      });
  }

  openGameDetails(id: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['details', id]);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.gameSub) {
      this.gameSub.unsubscribe();
    }

    if (this.routeSub) {
      this.routeSub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your params changes you have to subscribe to router events

```
constructor(router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
     if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       console.log(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('sparam'))
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: I tried it but i still got always null...

Comment: what is you add pathMatch: 'full'  to your '' route. like this :  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' 
  }

Comment: doesnt work either